# Solving a system of differential equations (Use of Dsolve?)

Tags: series-expansion

I am hoping to solve the equations as follows,

[image]

where 1H*, 3M* and 3E* are functions of t and all others are constants.
I tried the code,

```
HEqns = {H'[t] === ket*M1*H + G, H[0] == Hstar}
MEqns = {M'[t] == -kph*M - Q*kx*M1*M + ket*M1*H, M[0] == Mstar}
EEqns = {E'[t] == Q*kx*M1*M - kr*E, E[0] == Estar}
init = {M[0] == 0.001 M1, kph = 0.01 ket};
sol = DSolve[{HEqns, MEqns, EEqns}, {H[t], M[t], E[t]}, t]
```

but could not get any result back. Could I get any help please with this issue? Thank you!!

Comment: Copy and paste your code into your question rather than an image of the code.

Comment: Solving for y and v?  They don't exist in the equations.

Comment: Note that `DSolve` should have a capital `S`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for your comments, I edited the draft as suggested. Thank you!

Comment: You ought to pay attention to the errors.  They tell how to fix the code.  If you don't understand them, which happens now and then, ask about the error and how to fix it.  Otherwise, you will continue to struggle to use Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

I find the nomenclature somewhat confusing. But . . . I modified your code to be more consistent with Mathematica usage: 1) beginning all user variables in lower case; 2) all occurrences of the dependent variables are shown as dependent on t. For example, you use H'[t] on the left, so on the right H should appear as H[t]. (I use h[t].)

With these modifications the code below does produce a solution, which is complicated and so not shown.

```
hEqns = {h'[t] == ket m1 h [t] + g, h[0] == hStar};

mEqns = {m'[t] == -kph m[t] - q kx m1 m[t] + ket m1 h[t], 
   m[0] == mStar};

eEqns = {e'[t] == q kx m1 m[t] - kr e[t], e[0] == eStar};

DSolve[{hEqns, mEqns, eEqns}, {h[t], m[t], e[t]}, t];
```